# How to load Angular2 root component Dynamically

Tags: angular

I have a requirement where I have to load the root component in angular2 dynamically/using setTimeout().
Is is possible and how.
e.g.

```
<body>
 <hello-world>Loading...</hello-world>
</body>
```

I want the '*hello-world*' append after few second of page load. As I can't have custom component in the page load.

A plnkr will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add event on index page and listen this event in main.ts angular file.

index.html:

```
...  
<body>
    <my-app>Loading...</my-app>

    <script>
      setTimeout(function() {
          document.dispatchEvent(new Event('startNgLoad'))
      }, 5000)
    </script>
  </body>
...
```

main.ts:

```
document.addEventListener('startNgLoad', () => {
  platform.bootstrapModule(AppModule);
})
```

Comment: I cant have <my-app> tag in the beginning of index.html load. Can I append it dynamically and later do 'startNgLoad' ?

Comment: Yep, place `document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("my-app"))` before dispatch event, or before `platform.bootstrapModule()`

Answer (score 0):

You can load the root module inside the setTimeout in main.ts

```
setTimeout(function() {
  platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
},1000)
```

Comment: Is it possible setTimeout => insert('<hello-world>') after 5 seconds of set timeout